# how to declare variables and use them in css

Tags: css

I have following classes in css

```
.class1 {
ABC: 1s;
DEF: -1;
}

.class2 {
ABC: 2s;
DEF: -2;
}

.class3 {
ABC: 3s;
DEF: -3;
}
```

I tried to do this but not working

```
:root{
--my-number: varNumber;
}

.class{var(--my-number)} {
ABC: {var(--my-number)}s;
DEF: -{var(--my-number)};
}
```

as you can see these classes are similar except the numbers. I can access those numeric values in a variable from react component jsx. How CSS variables are set up so i can just pass that variable to class names and their properties?

Comment: Use a CSS preprocessor like sass/less or read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

Comment: i did go to that page but not sure how would i implement that in my case

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't do that with plain CSS. Take a look at Saas or Less, or some other language for writing enhanced CSS and compile it to plain CSS